# How to kill the session in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

m working on loginmodule. In logout module, m destroying the session. 
After logging out, If i click back button m getting the user information.
Please, help me to fix this bug.

Thanks

Comment: does it persist even if you hit refresh?

Comment: Thanks Herr, It persist even after hitting refresh

Answer (score 1):

$this->Auth->logout();
$this->Session->destroy();

Is that not doing it for you?

Comment: Thanks Ben,   I tried both, but its not working....  Do i need set any configuration?

Comment: $this->Session->destroy(); kills the session. here is the tests to prove it https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/tests/cases/libs/controller/components/session.test.php#L339 and the code that is called https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/cake/libs/cake_session.php#L456

Answer (score 0):

The reason being is that your browser has cached the page, so clicking back would always show the user information. There is not much you can do about this.

this might help http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/After-logout-browser-back-button-shows-all-visited-page-td1321477.html

Comment: I got the solution, As u told it was my browser problem only. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

HI,
If session->destroy does not work the try with Session->del('session name'); and for all session nma

Answer (score -1):

Its better to delete session using the "[$this->Session->delete('SessioName');](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1316/delete)

Comment: Funny you link to the docs but still get it wrong... that deletes something out of the session that was written like $this->Session->write('Stuff', $stuff); $this->Session->delete('Stuff');